# Burried via with custom shape in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, via

Does anyone know how to implement in Altium a buried via (a via in PCB inner layers) with e.g. rounded rectangle shape? E.g. i could define a pad with rounded rectangle shape and connections in inner layers, but the pad hole can go through full stack only.

I need this for a very specific design, and from manufacturer point of view this could be done. But, I would need advice on how to specify it properly in PCB design.

Perhaps there exists any other methods how to achieve this (specify a rounded rectangle shape slot with plated sides in PCB inner/core layer) with other methods?

Comment: Really curious why you need this

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find a "neat" soloution. Personally what I would probablly do is.

1. Place a regular blind via (preferablly a different size from all your other blind vias) in the middle of your hole somewhere so that the nets are joined up.
2. Draw what you want on an otherwise-unused mechanical layer.
3. Tell your PCB vendor what you have done.

Comment: Point #3 might have to be "Convince your PCB vendor to make this"